# Table mutli search - laravel - vue - api

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, search

I am trying to add mutli search to one table

the search is working but for one column only

here is my controller:

```
public function index()
{

    return Matter::when(request('search_client'), function($query){
        $query->where('client_company', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%')
        ->orWhere('matter_type', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%');
    })->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

}
```

i tried to do this:

```
public function index()
{

    return Matter::when(request('search_client'), function($query){
        $query->where('client_company', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%')
    })->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

    return Matter::when(request('search_file_ref'), function($query){
        $query->where('file_ref', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_ref') . '%')
    })->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

}
```

and assign the second method to another input but the first method works only, it doesn't return the second method

how can i assign same method or different method to specific input search?

here is the view:

```
<!-- SERACH CLIENT -->
                    <form @submit.prevent="searchClient">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input
                        v-model="search_client"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search Client"
                        class="form-control"
                    />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- SEARCH FILE REF -->
                    <form @submit.prevent="searchFileRef">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input
                        v-model="search_file_ref"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search File Ref"
                        class="form-control"
                    />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

script:

```
searchClient(){
        axios.get('/api/auth/matter?search_client=' + this.search_client)
        .then(response => this.matters = response.data)

    },
    searchFileRef(){
        axios.get('/api/auth/matter?search_file_ref=' + this.search_file_ref)
        .then(response => this.matters = response.data)

    },
```

so the first method in the controller will work but the second one won't

as you can see i have different search input for different column

what is the best practice to do the multi search for different column from different inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
public function index() {

$query = Matter::query();

$query->when(request('search_client','search_file_ref'), function($query){
$query->where('client_company', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%');
$query->where('file_ref', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_ref') . '%');
});



return $query->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

looking at the index method of your controller your code stops running at the return statement and you have two `return` so only the first will work since execution is stopped at that point.

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)

return returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.

If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.
[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

A correct approach would be:

```
public function index() {

  $query = Matter::query();

  $query->when(request('search_client'), function($query){
    $query->where('client_company', 'like', '%' . request('search_client') . '%')
  });

  $query::when(request('search_file_ref'), function($query){
    $query->where('file_ref', 'like', '%' . request('search_file_ref') . '%')
  });

  return $query->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
}
```

Comment: when i add this to my controller, i don't receive data from API but when i remove 'search_file_ref' query it works and when i add it it stop receiving data